# connect oracle in browser

Tags: php, linux, oracle, server

i had a server there is apache, php and oracle the configuration is complete from php.ini and path

but when i running script php in browser there always an error.

```
ci_pconnect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed.
```

and then when i'm running in terminal it's works..

NB: in apache env is complete

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/apps/oracle/client/client_1/lib
ORACLE_HOME=/apps/oracle/client/client_1
ORACLE_BASE=/apps/oracle
```

please help me fix this

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the same environment variables so that Apache can access them, and make sure that the Apache process has directory permissions to read the Oracle libraries.

How you set the environment depends on your OS and version of Apache.

For example, on RHEL 6 or Oracle Linux 6 you would add these to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/apps/oracle/client/client_1/lib
export ORACLE_HOME=/apps/oracle/client/client_1
export ORACLE_BASE=/apps/oracle
```

On RHEL 7 or Oracle Linux 7 you would add these to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/apps/oracle/client/client_1/lib
ORACLE_HOME=/apps/oracle/client/client_1
ORACLE_BASE=/apps/oracle
```

There are some other hints on p77 of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html